# Select from JSON_TABLE in where IN condition

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

I have this json in inc_list variable:

```
{"datalist":[
   {
     "idnumber":"123", 
     "value":"Name"   
   },
   {
     "idnumber":"999", 
     "value":"Name1"   
   }]
}
```

I need to use the value of *number" for IN clause in a select.
In my procedures I use this

```
            TYPE value_list_type IS TABLE OF varchar2(30);
            value_list value_list_type;

            SELECT VALUE BULK COLLECT                                    
            INTO VALUE_LIST
            FROM TABLE1
            WHERE TABLE1.id in
            (
                SELECT id 
                FROM JSON_TABLE(inc_list, '$.datalist[*]'
                    COLUMNS(id VARCHAR2 PATH '$.idnumber')
                )
            );
```

But it cause this error: `ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [qmxptAddDependency1]`

I can't understand why.

Can you help me?

Regards,
Marco

Comment: ORA-00600 errors are reserved for internal Oracle errors. What version of Oracle are you on? Do you have the latest patch set? If you are on the latest patch set for your version of Oracle, you may need to open a support ticket.

Comment: Apparently it is a known bug. Perhaps you can find a patch for your Oracle version. See https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4306720/json-table-used-for-in-clause#latest

Answer (score 2):

Experimentation (on a smaller test case) suggests that the `no_unnest` hint may prevent the Optimizer from performing an invalid operation (which seems to be the cause of this bug). Give it a try and see if it helps.

The query should look like this:

```
...
where table1.id in 
(
    select /*+ NO_UNNEST */ id         --  add /*+ NO_UNNEST */ here
    from json_table(.......)
    ...
)
```

Note that the exact syntax of the hint and the exact placement of the hint are essential. (Except that the hint can be lower case or upper case.)

Comment: Thanks for posting this - just got me out of a tight spot for a third-parties database we have to access.